# Loop keeps showing the same post even when I click on a different one

Tags: loop

So I am trying to build slider loop that shows posts related to a series, it seems to load the same post no matter what post I click on. I am using wp post format to differentiate posts between video, audio, gallery and standard.. I also am using wp post series plugin to tie posts together in groups, I have tried a bunch of different loops but this one seems to get me the closest. I need help =)

```
<?php
global $post;
$terms = get_terms('post_series');

foreach($terms as $term):
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'order'     => 'DESC',
                'taxonomy' => 'post_series',
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => array($term->slug)
            )
        ));
        $tag_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        if($tag_query->have_posts()):
             while($tag_query->have_posts()):$tag_query->the_post();
                get_template_part( 'parts/splide', 'seasonsHeroSlides' );
            endwhile; 
        endif; 
        wp_reset_postdata();
endforeach;
 ?>
```

Here is the code in the parts/splide-seasonsHeroSlides. I am using Advanced Custom Fields to pull data

```
<li class="splide__slide" data-equalizer>
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(''); ?> role="article" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
            <?php $image = get_field('media_featured_image'); ?>
            <div class="blurred-bg" style="background-image: url('<?php echo esc_url($image['url']); ?>');background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: 200%;background-position: center center;"></div>
            <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x grid-margin-x align-middle" style="padding: 60px 0;">
                <div class="small-12 cell">
                    <div class="grid-container">
                        <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x align-middle">
                            <div class="small-12 tablet-4 cell">
                                <?php $image = get_field('media_featured_image');
                                if( !empty( $image ) || the_post_thumbnail('full') ): ?>
                                    <img class="clear-img" src="<?php echo esc_url($image['url']); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr($image['alt']); ?>" />
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="small-12 tablet-6 cell">
                                <?php $media_name = get_field('media_name');
                                $contributor_name = get_field('contributor_name');
                                $sponsor_name = get_field('sponsor_name');
                                $rating = get_field('rating');
                                $media_type = get_field('media_type');
                                $year_release = get_field('year_release');
                                $media_category = get_field('media_category');
                                $media_description = get_field('media_description');
                                $media_attachment = get_field('media_attachment'); ?>
                                <h1 class="h2"><?php the_field('media_name'); ?></h1>
                                <div class="grid-x align-middle attr-contributor">
                                    <div class="small-12 cell">
                                        <?php $contributor_image = get_field('contributor_image');
                                        $size = 'full';
                                        if( $contributor_image ) {
                                            echo wp_get_attachment_image( $contributor_image, $size );
                                        } ?>
                                        <p><?php the_field('contributor_name'); ?><a href="#" aria-label="Follow this contributor">Follow</a></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="grid-x align-middle attr-sponsor">
                                    <div class="small-12 cell">
                                        <?php $sponsor_image = get_field('sponsor_image');
                                        $size = 'full';
                                        if( $sponsor_image ) {
                                            echo wp_get_attachment_image( $sponsor_image, $size );
                                        } ?>
                                        <p>Sponsored by: <a href="/sponsors/" class="sponsor-link"><?php the_field('sponsor_name'); ?></a></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <?php if( $media_category ): ?>
                                    <p><strong><?php the_field('rating'); ?> &#149; <?php echo implode( ', ', $media_category ); ?> &#149; <?php the_field('media_type'); ?> &#149; <?php the_field('year_release'); ?></strong></p>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <p><?php the_field('media_description'); ?></p>
                                <p><button class="button watch-media-trigger" data-toggle="play-screen">Start Watching Series</button></p>
                                <div class="large reveal" id="play-screen" data-reveal >
                                    <div class="play-video"><?php the_field('media_attachment'); ?></div>
                                    <p class="text-center text-white message" style="margin: 16px 0 0;"><small><strong>PLEASE BE PATIENT, YOUR VIDEO MAY NEED A MOMENT TO BUFFER.</strong></small></p>
                                    <button class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close reveal" type="button">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <script>

                                        var video = jQuery('video')[0];
                                        jQuery('button').click(function() {
                                            if( video.paused ) {
                                                video.play();
                                                setTimeout(function(){
                                                    jQuery(".message").fadeOut(400);
                                                }, 10000)
                                            }
                                            else {
                                                video.pause();
                                            }
                                        });


                                    </script>
                                </div>
                            <div class="small-12 large-2 cell"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </article>
</li>
```

Comment: the problem might be with the template which you are calling with ` get_template_part( 'parts/splide', 'seasonsHeroSlides' );` -  what is the code of that?

Comment: I added the code to the post 'parts/splide', 'seasonsHeroSlides'. I am using Advanced Custom Field's plugin to pull in data